# ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll not on nuget (included manually)

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I was just reviewing my project's dependencies, and I remembered something I did a while ago.

When I first included the Validation Feature, i browsed servicestack's source, and since it was at ServiceInterface.dll and that wasn't at nuget, I just compiled it manually, and manually included the library. However I want to include it through nuget.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks
(using 3.9.71)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll** has always been included in the [ServiceStack v3 NuGet packages](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/3.9.71), you can inspect the contents of NuGet packages using the [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/):

[image]

Comment: Ah. Since I keep everything decoupled, I have the habit of doing -force on dependencies I don't target (e.g., uninstall-package ServiceStack.Redis). In this case it is validation only DLL, without infrastructure/endpoint stuff, that's y i did it